# High Availability AEM Author

Tags: aem, infrastructure

I’ve been working with AEM for over a year now and lately I’ve been trying to move into a high availability setup for author.

My problem is when ever I spin up a server, add sites, and spin up another server the data doesn’t persist to the new instance. I know why this doesn’t work in the traditional setup (repository is stored locally on the file system). However, I’ve attempted using the S3 backend, and it results in the same problem where the data doesn’t persist onto the new instance.

Ive read about using mongoMK (https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/recommended-deploys.html), I.e. mongodb as a store, but they also recommended using S3 as the backend.

My question is, does anyone have any experience with multiple AEM author instances sharing the same data and node stores, if so do you have any suggestions as to how to get this working or resources where I can read about this?

After further research it seems the *only* option for backend clustering is to use mongodb. My attempts to use mongodb with AEM as a backend have failed. When I attempt to use the crx3 and crx3mongo run modes it looks like AEM hangs after opening a connection to mongo. I have verified that nothing is getting placed into the DB via a `show dbs` returning `0.000GB` for the corresponfing database.

Comment: When using MongoDB or S3 you are installing an instance from scratch, correct? The platform doesn't let you switch data storage models after initialization.

Comment: The issue was, I needed to add BOTH the config files in the /crx-quickstart/install as well as on the install add both crx3,crx3mongo run modes and the -Dmongo.url option when starting up. Going to give a more detailed answer when I get some time.